# ctype tag? Why?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I was looking at this question: [Assertion Failure on function using ispunct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664630/assertion-failure-on-function-using-ispunct)

and saw that there's a [ctype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ctype) tag with 0 followers and no description at all. What is it? I hope that isn't referring to the `ctype.h` header.

Comment: It's a mixture of, at least, C's `ctype.h` header and Python's `ctypes` library (misspelling for [tag:ctypes]). It needs to be disambiguated.

Comment: is it useful to have a tag for ctype.h? In that case there should be tags for each C and C++ major header

Comment: I think these questions should be tagged with [tag:locale] if the locale is relevant and nothing particular if the locale isn't relevant. So no, I don't see the point of a `ctype.h` tag.

Comment: [tag:ctype] has now 68 questions and is used in vb.net, c, php, python and a bunch of other questions...

Comment: Can we upgrade this question to a retag request to get the [tag:ctype] clear of questions? I can handle the vb.net ones and php but I'm unsure about the others

Comment: If we decide it should stay can somebody propose a tag wiki and excerpt in that case?

Comment: Added retag request